# Can I combine a parameter with a variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I have these lines of code:

```
if [[  $1 = "-x" ]]
then
    echo "some message"
fi
```

but what I want is the `-x` to be followed by a number, like `-x 3`

How do I put a variable next to `-x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getopts` function which is inbuilt like:

```
while getopts ":x" opt; do
case "${opt}" in
    x)
        x=${OPTARG}
        ;;
```

So when you call your script, you could run as `script.sh -x 3`

Comment: Then you would need to do something like: `if [[ A$2 == 'A-x' ]] then x=$3 fi`