# How can I list a specific line/word from my text?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this until now:

```
if [[ $1 = "-s" ]] && [[ $2 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
    echo "ok"
    for $2 = 1 awk {print $1} something.txt
fi
```

What I want is, for example, when I enter `-s 2`, to list the second word of every line first!

I already know the `for` part is wrong.

Comment: Crossposting: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254281/how-can-i-list-a-specific-line-word-from-my-textshellscript

Comment: yes but they didnt help there :p

Comment: In [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34696232/2088135) you were advised to use `getopts` and you accepted an answer that showed you how to use it. Why have you gone for this approach?

Comment: nop i accept it cause was hepfull but not what i wanted! i asked the guy that answered me if he had something different and he helped me again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
for $2 = 1 awk {print $1} something.txt
```

by

```
awk -v var="$2" '{print $var}' something.txt
```